# How to combine photos and text into one attachment for sending mail through iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email-attachments, email

I want to use MFMailComposeViewController to send an email with attachments of both photos and text attached automatically. I know how to attach and send each individual text and photo by converting to NSData separately, but i need to combine them into one attachment. Is there a way to do that? perhaps create a zip file?

Comment: Create a PDF with the photos and text or zip up the photos and a text file.

Comment: How would you do it in ordinary life? Suppose you wanted to send a single attachment containing photos and text from your desktop computer? How would you do it? Do that.

Comment: I looked into creating a zip, there are libraries that facilitate that, but i realized you cant open zip files in iOS mail. so is there a way to attach the text and images using a multipart mime? i have never used that but i read somewhere that it might work for my requirement

Comment: I think you need send mail with HTML body, where all attached photos will be displayed in text.